# How to style the date module

Tags: 7, datetime

How can I style the [Date Module](http://drupal.org/project/date) as noted in the image below?  Which hooks/functions would be involved?

Is there a better Date input widget for Drupal 7?

I'm using Drupal 7 and the Date module is currently 7.x-2.0-alpha4.

[image: Changes I Would Like To Make].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have to see the html, but find the class that wraps each field (the border is applied to that) and use a float left with some right margin. Find what class wraps both of them and apply overflow:hidden to that. The fields should now look like what you want.

Comment: This coupled with `drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/path/file.css')` worked beautifully.