# Date Field: Two Date fields for two dates or using "End date"-property?

Tags: 7, datetime

for my hotel rating website, I want to give my users the possibility to write the start date and the end date of their trip into their comment.

For this purpose I'm using the date module (https://drupal.org/project/date). Currently I use the Start date and the end date in one field.

Is it better to create one date field and using the "end date" property or should I create two separate date fields?

The end result should look like this one here: [How to style the date module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12189/how-to-style-the-date-module)

Are there any alternative modules which also achieve these results?

Thanks for any help.